# Default value for file path in function gives SyntaxError. Work around?

Tags: python, function, default-value

for this,

```
import os.path

def f(data_file_path=os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'temp'),type):
    ...
    return data
```

I get this,

```
SyntaxError: non-default argument follows default argument
```

Is there a way to make this work or do I have to define a variable such as,

```
rawdata_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'temp')
```

and then plug that into the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `type` before `data_file_path`

```
def f(type,data_file_path=os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'temp')):
```

Assigning values in the function parameter called default arguments, those should come afther non-default arguments

Answer (score 0):

You have to switch the order of the arguments. Mandatory arguments (without default values) must come before arguments with set default values.

Answer (score 0):

Rearrange the parameters:

```
def f(type, data_file_path=os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'temp')):
    pass
```

The reason for this is, that arguments with default values can be omitted.
But of you call `f('foo')`, it is not know if you want to set the `type` and omit `data_file_path` or not.

Answer (score 0):

Arguments with a default value should be placed after all arguments without a default value.

Change it to:

```
import os.path

def f(type, data_file_path=os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'temp')):
    ...
    return data
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind.

```
SyntaxError: non-default argument follows default argument
```

refers to the order of the arguments so,

```
def f(type,data_file_path=os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'temp')):
```

works!

me newbie